# Props in functional component are missing in props validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, react-proptypes

Eslint throwing eslint(react/prop-types) error despite already declared propTypes. I'm using [eslint-plugin-react](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react)

I've looked at a couple of other similar problems and as well as the [lint rule for the proptype](https://github.com/Intellicode/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md) but they don't address my issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const PASTEL_PINK = '#dea5a4';
const PASTEL_BLUE = '#779ecb';

const Buttons = ({ onPressStart, onPressPause, onPressReset, onGoing }) => (
  <View >
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={onPressStart}
      disabled={onGoing}
    >
      <Text >{START_TIMER}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={onPressPause}
      disabled={!onGoing}
    >
      <Text >{PAUSE_TIMER}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPressReset}>
      <Text >{RESET_TIMER}</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  </View>
);

Buttons.protoTypes = {
  onPressStart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onPressPause: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onPressReset: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onGoing: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default Buttons;
```

Parent component supplying the props

```
import React from 'react';
import Buttons from './components/Buttons'
import Container from './components/Container';
import Timer from './components/Timer';
import Inputs from './components/Inputs';
import Logo from './components/Logo';
import Buttons from './components/Buttons'
import Header from './components/Header'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      initialMinute: '00',
      initialSecond: '00',
      minute: '00',
      second: '00',
      completed: false,
      onGoing: false,
    }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        minute: this.state.initialMinute,
        second: this.state.initialSecond,
      }
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  startTimer = () => {
    console.log("Timer Started")
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => (
        {
          completed: false,
          onGoing: true,
        }
      )
    )
    // start the timer
    this.interval = setInterval(
      this.decrementTime,
      1000
    )
  }

  decrementTime = () => {
    if (this.state.second > 0) {
      console.log(`second: ${this.state.second}`)
      this.setState(
        (prevState) => (
          {second: prevState.second - 1}
        )
      )
      if (this.props.second < 10) {
        this.setState({
            second: '0'+this.state.second
        });
      }
    }
    else {
      if (this.state.minute > 0) {
        this.setState(
          (prevState) => (
            {
              minute: prevState.minute - 1,
              second: prevState.second + 59,
            }
          )
        )
        if (this.props.minute < 10) {
          this.setState({
              state: '0'+this.state.minute
          });
        }
      }
      else {
        this.resetTimer();
        this.timesUp(true);
      }
    }
  }

  pauseTimer = () => {
    console.log("Timer stopped")
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.setState({
        onGoing: false,
      }
    )
  }

  resetTimer = () => {
    console.log("Timer is reset")
    this.pauseTimer();
    this.setState({
        minute: this.state.initialMinute,
        second: this.state.initialSecond,
      }
    );
  }

  timesUp = (bool) => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => (
        {
          completed: bool,
        }
      )
    )
  }


  optionPressed = () => {
    console.log("Header is pressed")
  }

  handleMinuteInput = (text) => {
    // clamp minute between 0 and 60
    // const number = helper.clamp(parseInt(text), 0, 60)
    this.setState(
      {
        initialMinute: text,
      }
    )
  }

  handleSecondInput = (text) => {
    // const number = helper.clamp(parseInt(text+''), 0, 60)
    this.setState(
      {
        initialSecond: text,
      }
    )
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header onPress={this.optionPressed}/>
          <Logo 
            slogan={'Get studying, the Pomodoro way!'}
            imageSource={'../../assets/pomo-timer-logo-small.png'}
          />
          <Timer 
            minute={this.state.minute}
            second={this.state.second}
            completed={this.state.completed}
            onGoing={this.state.onGoing}
          />
          <Buttons 
            onPressStart={this.startTimer}
            onPressPause={this.pauseTimer}
            onPressReset={this.resetTimer}
            onGoing={this.state.onGoing} // true when not onGoing
          />
          <Inputs 
            inputType={'Work'}
            labelColor={PASTEL_BLUE}
            handleMinuteInput={this.handleMinuteInput}
            handleSecondInput={this.handleSecondInput}
            onGoing={this.state.onGoing}
          />
          <Inputs
            inputType={'Rest'}
            labelColor={PASTEL_PINK}
            // setTimer={this.setTimer}
            handleMinuteInput={this.handleMinuteInput}
            handleSecondInput={this.handleSecondInput}
            onGoing={this.state.onGoing}
          />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

I don't expect these error to show up but it does.

'onPressStart' is missing in props validation
'onPressPause' is missing in props validation
'onPressReset' is missing in props validation
'onGoing' is missing in props validation

Comment: Can you post the code of whatever is giving this component it's props?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace

```
Buttons.protoTypes
```

with

```
Buttons.propTypes
```

I have done this mistake too many times

Comment: Thank you! I make way too many of these mistakes and not notice it.

Answer (score 1):

It's `propTypes`, not `protoTypes` :)